# Slides presentation using R

Tags: r, r-markdown

I was watching this RStudio talk on Youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f39_oW4RKfI) and from this talk I found this amazing way of presenting slides in here: http://inundata.org/talks/rstd19/#/

I was wondering what were the tools/methods used to create this presentation (supposing you own a domain name).

I am familiar with RMarkdown but I don't think this is enough to create this kind of presentation.

I contacted the author of the presentation but I never got an answer so I am trying here, if this is not the best forum for this type of topic please let me know where I shoud post.
Thanks !

Comment: Probably `xaringan` See <https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/xaringan.html> and you host it using GitHub pages assuming you put everything on GitHub. Workflow works for Git*** and you could self host with Netifly

Comment: Amazing! This definitely looks like this is the package that has been used. Thx a ton